# Drawing a Chart From CLI Using LibreOffice

Tags: command-line, bash, libreoffice

I have a file that contains two columns of values, so I am looking for a way to draw a chart from my CLI. In another word, I need a **script** that reads the file that contains the values and represents it as a chart from my CLI.

My question is: Is there such a way to do that maybe using LibreOffice or another App?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) instead.

Ex. let's generate some simple tab delimited data:

```
$ for i in {1..100..10}; do printf '%d\t%d\n' $i $((RANDOM%100)); done > datafile

$ cat datafile
1   16
11  14
21  79
31  96
41  68
51  93
61  50
71  13
81  32
91  91
```

then for example

```
$ gnuplot -p -e 'plot "datafile" using 1:2 with linespoints'
```

gives the following

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Nasser_Omar you're welcome - I'm not saying there *isn't* a way to do it in LibreOffice, although if there is I doubt it will be simpler than the above. You could also check out [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your help